# How to make two buttons on the same row in eclipse programmatically?

Tags: android, eclipse

```
LinearLayout table = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

btnControl = new Button(this);
    btnControl.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btnControl.setPadding(0,40,0,40);//x,y,w,h
    btnControl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C344E"));
    btnControl.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    setMargins(btnControl, 50, 50, 50, 50);

btnLogs = new Button(this);
        btnLogs.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(380, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnLogs.setPadding(0,40,0,40);//x,y,w,h
        btnLogs.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#1C344E"));
        btnLogs.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        setMargins(btnLogs, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        btnLogs.setId(5);
        btnLogs.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnTermLogs = new Button(this);
        btnTermLogs.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(380, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btnTermLogs.setPadding(0,40,0,40);//x,y,w,h
        btnTermLogs.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CC6675"));
        btnTermLogs.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        setMargins(btnLogs, 50, 50, 50, 50);
        btnTermLogs.setId(6);
        btnTermLogs.setOnClickListener(this);

btnLogout = new Button(this);
    btnLogout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    btnLogout.setPadding(0,40,0,40);//x,y,w,h
    btnLogout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CC6675"));
    btnLogout.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    table.addView(btnLogs);
        table.addView(btnTermLogs);
```

I want the two buttons to be aligned together horizontally. However it just align themselves vertically which i dont want.

My buttons look like this:

[image: NO]

what i want is to look like this:
[image: YES]

Comment: @intelliJ Amiya, the duplicate site you gave me is all of the buttons are inside the loop. i have another buttons that needs to be vertically aligned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below function. It will help

```
public void addButtons(){
    LinearLayout table = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);

    LinearLayout linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams LayoutParamsview = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    Button button1 = new Button(this);
    button1.setText("Btn 1");
    button1.setLayoutParams(LayoutParamsview);

    linearLayout1.addView(button1);
    table.addView(linearLayout1);

    //
    LinearLayout linearLayout2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    Button button2 = new Button(this);
    button2.setText("Btn 2");
    button2.setLayoutParams(LayoutParamsview);

    Button button3 = new Button(this);
    button3.setText("Btn 3");
    button3.setLayoutParams(LayoutParamsview);

    linearLayout2.addView(button2);
    linearLayout2.addView(button3);
    table.addView(linearLayout2);

    //
    LinearLayout linearLayout3 = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout3.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    Button button4 = new Button(this);
    button4.setText("Btn 4");
    button4.setLayoutParams(LayoutParamsview);

    linearLayout3.addView(button4);
    table.addView(linearLayout3);

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- You should use [**`setLayoutParams`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))
- Add **`setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);`**

> Set the layout parameters associated with this view. These supply
>   parameters to the parent of this view specifying how it should be
>   arranged. There are many subclasses of ViewGroup.LayoutParams, and
>   these correspond to the different subclasses of ViewGroup that are
>   responsible for arranging their children.

**Code Structure**

```
    LinearLayout table = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
    table.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    Button Btn1 = new Button(Activity.this);
    Btn1.setText("Button 1");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam.weight = 0.5f;
    Btn1.setLayoutParams(childParam);

    Button Btn2 = new Button(Activity.this);
    Btn2.setText("Button 2");
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    childParam2.weight = 0.5f;
    Btn2.setLayoutParams(childParam2);

    table.addView(Btn1);
    table.addView(Btn2);
```

**Respected OP**

[image]

Comment: i updated my question :) the encircled buttons are the only ones that i need to aligned horizontally

Comment: @ulyk Kindly check my answer.

Comment: it is aligning my two buttons vertically not horizontally :( and the https://www.android-examples.com/creating-horizontal-linearlayout-programmatically-android/ site you gave me is all of its button are aligned horizontally. However in my case, i have two buttons that are aligned vertically and another two buttons that i am aligning horizontally right now based on my image.

Comment: it will affect my other buttons :( if i put setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

Comment: in my image i have button 0 and button 3 that ishould not be affected by the changes applied to button 1 and 2

Comment: @ulyk for this functionality you should add `setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);` . So create a Another `LINEARLAYOUT`

Answer (score 1):

You can create another `XML` file, that contains a horizontal `LinearLayout`, then inflate it and insert the two buttons into it, and then add the whole horizontal `LinearLayout` to the vertical `LinearLayout`:

1. Create an `XML` file e.g. `horizontal_layout.xml`:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/horizontal_layout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

   // You will insert the buttons programmatically.

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. In your Activity use this method to inflate the `Layout`:

   ```
       LinearLayout verticalLinearLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.vertical_linear_layout);

   // Add the first vertical Button regularly.
   Button firstVerticalButton = new Button(Activity.this);
   firstVerticalButton.setText("Vertical");
   verticalLinearLayout.addView(firstVerticalButton);

   // Inflate the horizontal LinearLayout and add the two horizontal buttons.
   LinearLayout horizontalLinearLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.horizontal_layout,
           linearLayout, false);

   Button horizontalOne = new Button(Activity.this);
   horizontalOne.setText("Horizontal");
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   childParam1.weight = 0.5f;
   horizontalOne.setLayoutParams(childParam);

   Button horizontalTwo = new Button(Activity.this);
   horizontalTwo.setText("Horizontal");
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   childParam1.weight = 0.5f;
   horizontalTwo.setLayoutParams(childParam2);

   horizontalLinearLayout.addView(horizontalOne);
   horizontalLinearLayout.addView(horizontalTwo);

   // Insert the inflated layout to the main layout.
   verticalLinearLayout.addView(horizontalLinearLayout);

   // Add the second vertical Button
   Button secondVerticalButton = new Button(Activity.this);
   secondVerticalButton.setText("Vertical");
   verticalLinearLayout.addView(secondVerticalButton);
   ```

Comment: This will make all buttons vertical except those two buttons.

Comment: your code helped me even though your code is not by programmatically, however my two buttons is at the top of my button0, how to make it at the center? I am doing the code programmatically

Comment: Insert the button0 before you inflate the horizontal `LinearLayout`, and add it to the vertical one, so it will be the first one, then inflate the horizontal `LinearLayout` and insert the two buttons you want to be aligned horizontally (button1 + button 2) then add the whole horizontal `Layout` to the vertical `Layout`, so far the button0 is at the top, and button1 + button2 below it, the last step is to add button3 to the vertical `Layout` and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

> Horizontal linear layout supports left to right widgets approach, When
>   app developer selects horizontal orientation in linear layout then it
>   will automatically start adding components and widgets to left to
>   right side after adding them. So here is the complete step by step
>   tutorial for Creating horizontal linearlayout programmatically
>   android.

Write this code

```
     //Creating LinearLayout.
     LinearLayout Horizontallinearlayout = new LinearLayout(this);

     //Setting up LinearLayout Orientation
     Horizontallinearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

     LayoutParams Horizontallinearlayoutlayoutparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 

     setContentView(Horizontallinearlayout, Horizontallinearlayoutlayoutparams);

     LayoutParams LayoutParamsview = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

     //Creating textview .
     Button button1 = new Button(this);
     Button button2 = new Button(this);

     //Adding text to TextView.
     button1.setText("First Button");
     button2.setText("Second Button");

     button1.setLayoutParams(LayoutParamsview);
     button2.setLayoutParams(LayoutParamsview);

     //Adding textview to linear layout using Add View function.
     Horizontallinearlayout.addView(button1);
     Horizontallinearlayout.addView(button2);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: @ulyk Thank you. happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

use `table.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);` .

Hope it Helps.

Comment: i updated my question :) the encircled buttons are the only ones that i need to aligned horizontally